# How to add error handler for producer when using spring Kafka

Tags: spring-kafka

How to add error handler for producer when using spring Kafka? I know how to add error handler for consumer but I am not sure about producer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `KafkaTemplate`:

```
/**
 * Set a {@link ProducerListener} which will be invoked when Kafka acknowledges
 * a send operation. By default a {@link LoggingProducerListener} is configured
 * which logs errors only.
 * @param producerListener the listener; may be {@code null}.
 */
public void setProducerListener(ProducerListener<K, V> producerListener) {
    this.producerListener = producerListener;
}
```

And that one has this:

```
/**
 * Invoked after an attempt to send a message has failed.
 * @param topic the destination topic
 * @param partition the destination partition (could be null)
 * @param key the key of the outbound message
 * @param value the payload of the outbound message
 * @param exception the exception thrown
 */
void onError(String topic, Integer partition, K key, V value, Exception exception);
```

Comment: would this listener get executed in case of failed construct kafka producer, like incorrect password ? `java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed`

Comment: I think so. we really connect from producer to Kafka lazy when the send is executed already.

Comment: Late comment here, How about TopicAuthorizationException?

Comment: What about that? See `ProduceResponse` JavaDocs. There is that `Errors.TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED` mentioned based on this error.